# Predicting the square root of a number using Machine Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to create a program in python that uses machine learning to predict the square root of a number. I am listing what all I have done in my program:-

1. created a csv file with numbers and their squares
2. extracted the data from csv into suitable variables (X stores squares, y stores numbers)
3. scaled the data using sklearn's, StandardScaler
4. built the ANN with two hidden layers each of 6 units (no activation functions)
5. compiled the ANN using SGD as the optimizer and mean squared error as the loss function
6. trained the model. Loss was around 0.063
7. tried predicting but the result is something else.

**My actual code**:-

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CSV/SQUARE-ROOT.csv')

X = df.iloc[:, 1].values
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df.iloc[:, 0].values
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_test_sc = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
X_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
sc1 = StandardScaler()
y_test_sc1 = sc1.fit_transform(y_test)
y_train_sc1 = sc1.fit_transform(y_train)

ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))

ann.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

ann.fit(x = X_train_sc, y = y_train_sc1, batch_size=5, epochs = 100)

print(sc.inverse_transform(ann.predict(sc.fit_transform([[144]]))))
```

**OUTPUT**:- `array([[143.99747]], dtype=float32)`

Shouldn't the output be 12? Why is it giving me the wrong result?

I am attaching the csv file I used to train my model as well: [SQUARE-ROOT.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCyu62Doj0O72zB7QSiSG1hCkcNkVXAR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you are using machine learning, it is not predicting. It is calculating (assuming your training is proper). Because machine learning algorithms include mathematical metrics to "predict", making it essentially calculate.

Comment: I am still a beginner in this field. I am really sorry if I mess up the terms :( I think my training is proper as the loss generated was low. I don't know if I am right on this regard. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, the terms you used were accurate. What I mean is how Machine Learning works in the backend. For mathematical stuff, it calculates and not predicts. But yes, the function used to trigger it is called "predict", so you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because you apply `fit_transform` to your test set, which is wrong. You can fix it by replacing `fit_transform(test)` to `transform(test)`. Although I don't think `StandardScaler` is neccessary, please try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

N = 10000
X = np.arange(1, N).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.sqrt(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.2)


sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_sc = sc.fit_transform(X_train)    
#X_test_sc = sc.fit_transform(X_test)      # wrong!!!
X_test_sc = sc.transform(X_test)

sc1 = StandardScaler()       
y_train_sc1 = sc1.fit_transform(y_train)    
#y_test_sc1 = sc1.fit_transform(y_test)   # wrong!!!
y_test_sc1 = sc1.transform(y_test)

ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))    # you have 10000 data, maybe you need a little deeper network
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))

ann.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='MSE')
ann.fit(x=X_train_sc, y=y_train_sc1, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_test_sc, y_test_sc1))

#print(sc.inverse_transform(ann.predict(sc.fit_transform([[144]]))))  # wrong!!!
print(sc1.inverse_transform(ann.predict(sc.transform([[144]]))))
```

Comment: OMG! Your code works like charm! I have a doubt. Hope you will clear them out. Why is there a need for introducing much deeper network? Is it because of less data inputs? Will it suffice instead of increasing the units, I increase the epochs? Thank you :)

Comment: Because your model seems a bit underfitting, that's why I suggest using a deeper network. Increase the epochs works too when the model has not yet converged. You can confirm it by plotting a graph. My model isn't perfect too. You need to fine tune it and try different parameters.

Comment: If that happens, try using a much smaller learning rate.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: You really need those nonlinearities.

The reason behind it not working could be one (or a combination) of several causes, like bad input data range, flaws in your data, over/underfitting, etc.

However, in this specific case the model you build literally can't learn the function you're trying to approximate, because **not having nonlinearities makes this a purely linear model**, which can't accurately approximate nonlinear functions.

A `Dense` layer is implemented as follows:

```
x_res = activ_func(w*x + b)
```

where `x` is the layer input, `w` the weights, `b` the bias vector and `activ_func` the activation function (if one is defined).

Your model, then, mathematically becomes (I'm using indices 1 to 3 for the three Dense layers):

```
pred = w3 * (w2 * ( w1 * x + b1 ) + b2 ) + b3
     = w3*w2*w1*x + w3*w2*b1 + w3*b2 + b3
```

As you see, the resulting model is still linear.
Add activation functions and your mode becomes capable of learning nonlinear functions too. From there, experiment with the hyperparameters and see how the performance of your model changes.